# spring Hibernate Multi SessionFactories and TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-data

i am a newbie to spring and hibernate..Here in my scenario, i am building an application where it can connect to different environments Db's(devl,qual,prod) based on the environment selected by the user..For this I am making multiple SessionFactory beans and distinguishing them using @Qualifier in DAO classes based on the env selected by the user..

Here i am struck at, how to configure multi-TransactionManagers if they are required or not in my case and how to deal with the code if the multi-TransactionManagers are not required..?
So I was not sure of how to use different TransactionManagers per env, for the same save method which will save the user form data in the DB..Below is my spring .xml file and the DAO class code which is used to distinguish the sessionFactory w.r.t env..

Help needed in configuring multiple TransactionManagers or can I discard the use of TransactionManager and simply distinguish the transaction with Hibernate session(beginTransaction)..!!

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceProd" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSourceProd" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SM_PROD" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Hibernate Properties -->
     <bean id="prodSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceProd" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.deere.dsfj.siteMinder.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSourceDevl" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SM_Devl" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="DevlSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDevl" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.deere.dsfj.siteMinder.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Below is the DAO code..

```
public void BeginTransaction(String targetEnv)
    {
        getCurrentSession(targetEnv).getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("DevlSessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory devlSessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("prodSessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory prodSessionFactory;

    protected final Session getCurrentSession(String targetEnv)
    {
          if(targetEnv!=null && !"".equals(targetEnv) && targetEnv.equals("Devl"))
          {
              return devlSessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
          }
          else if(targetEnv!=null && !"".equals(targetEnv) && targetEnv.equals("PROD"))
          {
              return prodSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          }

          return null;

    }
```

Appreciate the help...

Comment: You don't need multiple session factories, only datasources. Use an `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to select the needed datasource based on the user selection. That way you only need a single transaction manager and it will reduce your code complexity. Also your configuration for hibernate is flawed don't set the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` as that breaks proper tx integration and when you have that in place you can use Spring to manage your transactions.

Comment: HI Deinum, i am a newbie and not sure on how to implement AbstractRoutingDataSource..can you pls provide an example on that..and also is it ok, if i dont use the spring transactionManager at all and relying only on Hibernate to manage the transaction( i.e., using session to open and commit the transactions with out using spring to manage them..?)

Comment: You can but why... It is error prone and repetitive stuff, use the framework don't work around it. Your solution will even make it worse as you have configured a `DataSourceTransactionManager` instead of the correct one for your technology a `HibernateTransactionManager`.

Comment: thanks Deinum..Actaully i am a newbie and not sure of how to use TransactionManager..so i made the change in the xml file by removing the TransactionManger property itself and relying totally on Hibernate, as i dont know other way to do using spring Transaction..If you got some time, can u pls help me, on making AbstractRoutingDataSource ..?

Comment: See https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: thanks for the info Deinum..will go through that..